# Prove that in HoTT if types $A$ and $B$ are connected and $\Omega A = \Omega B$, then $A = B$

Tags: homotopy-type-theory, loop-spaces

In Homotopy Type Theory, suppose that $A, B : \mathcal{U}$, and $a_0 : A$ and $b_0 : B$.

Further, suppose that A and B are connected, so we have $\prod_{a:A}||a_0 = a||$ and likewise for B.

Finally suppose that $(a_0 = a_0) = (b_0 = b_0)$.

Is it possible from these conditions to prove that $A=B$? From my understanding of types as $\infty-$groupoids, it seems that it should be possible.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  It's certainly true that if you have a *map* $f:A\to B$ which *induces* the equivalence $\Omega A \simeq \Omega B$, then connectedness of $A$ and $B$ implies that $f$ is itself an equivalence (this is in the HoTT Book).  But absent a given map, and absent a "delooping machine" to reconstruct $A$ from $\Omega A$ (delooping machines in classical algebraic topology require infinite structures and are not yet definabel in plain HoTT), I'm not sure how to attack the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

Consider the Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces $K(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2,1)$ and $K(\mathbb{Z}_4,1)$. Those are non-equivalent connected types with equivalent (hence equal) loop spaces. The issue here is that the equivalence of loop spaces is just an equivalence between two 4-element types, but not a group isomorphism.

Comment: Oh of course! Maybe it would be true if I required them to be equal as groups rather than just as types, but I won't go there because that sounds hard to define in HoTT.